# How to get the textbox values which are generated dynamically using razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
    <tr>
        @foreach (string s in "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15".Split(','))
        {  

            <td>@Html.TextBox("Time","")
            </td>
            <p>
            </p>

        }
    </tr>
```

How i get the values from textboxes created above using either javascript or jquery.
kindly assist me

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

```
$('input[name=Time]').each(function(index, element){
    var txtValue = element.value;
});
```